# Input no longer accepts user values when the result of a calculation is supposed to be written to it

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a simple form with five inputs, just like the one below. The numerical data entered by the user is used to plot a Google Piechart. Worked without a hitch before I added a snippet of HTML/Javascript code in form of a small calculator.

```
<tr>
    <td>Indicele de masa corporala, kg/m<sup>2</sup></td>
    <td><input size="4" type="text" maxlength="5" id="imc" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="keyUp(this.value);" onkeydown="this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, '.');" required="required"/></td>
  </tr>
```

I also have a small BMI calculator with two inputs placed in the same page but one table row before the form, normally hidden and only displayed at the click of a button (through Javascript), which calculates via Javascript the BMI value and writes the result in the input above.

```
<tr>
    <td><label class="IMCCalc">Greutate, kg</label></td>
    <td><input id="Greutate" type="text" size="1" min="1" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="keyUp(this.value);" onkeydown="this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, '.');" required="required" /></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><label class="IMCCalc">Inaltime, m</label></td>
    <td>    <input id="Inaltime" size="1" type="text" min="1" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="keyUp(this.value);" onkeydown="this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, '.');" required="required"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Calculeaz&#259;" onclick="Converteste();"/></td>
  </tr>

    function Converteste() {
  var ValoareaInaltime = parseFloat(document.getElementById('Inaltime').value);
  var ValoareaGreutate = parseFloat(document.getElementById('Greutate').value);
  var ValoareaIMC = ValoareaGreutate / (ValoareaInaltime ** 2);
  const ValoareaIMCajustata = Math.floor(ValoareaIMC * 100) / 100;
  document.getElementById('imc').value = ValoareaIMCajustata.toFixed(2);       
}
```

Since I added the HTML/Javascript code for the BMI calculator the problem is that when I add data manually to all five inputs the chart is not displayed but when the BMI calculator writes the result to the input with id="imc" the chart is displayed. If I eliminate the Javascript function of the BMI calculator the chart does not work with manually-added data. If I eliminate the html code BMI calculator the form with the five inputs works again with manually-added data. The input with id="imc" must accept either user-entered data or the result of the BMI calculation. It is obvious that the problem lies with the html code of the BMI calculator and the input with id="imc" but I can not figure it out. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Your problem description is counter-intuitive to what one would expect. Displaying of your chart appers to be triggered by the `onkeyup="keyUp(this.value);"` on the input fields - which should only trigger when the user actually types into the field; setting the value _via script_, which is what your second code block is doing, should not trigger that event in the first place. So what you say is happening, is the exact opposite of what one would expect here. Please provide us with a proper [mre] of the whole thing, so that we can see what is actually going on.

Comment: CBroe, onkeyup="keyUp(this.value);" onkeydown="this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, '.');"  convert automatically comma to dot. I am working on providing a minimal example.

Comment: I suggest you delegate and do not have inline event handlers

Comment: I can not get Stacksnippet to work, the page source here will give the code.

www.metabolicanalysis.eu/GC1.html

To see what I mean, in the upper left panel fill the form with five numerical values and press Evalueaza. Nothing happens in the right panel although I want the chart to appear. 

Now press the button Calculeaza IMC, fill the two inputs. Press button Calculeaza below and one of the five inputs will change value. If I press the button Terminat to close the calc the chart appears, which I do not want.  

If I press now the button Evalueaza the chart appears, which is OK!

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: keyUp is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (GC1.html:252:183)` - please look in the console while you click around. Create it or remove the reference